# Windows - Alt Click on a window to close window under the mouse cursor

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, autohotkey

Is it possible to close a window, simply by clicking anywhere inside it? Hold down alt key, and click the windows you want closed. Much like shooting targets in a game.

Why not Alt+F4? This would be more useful because Alt+F4 requires the window to be active. If not, you have to click on the window to bring it to the front first. An extra step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AltSnap](https://github.com/RamonUnch/AltSnap/wiki), free and open source program, allows you do that and more (drag/resize window while holding the ALT button). It works perfectly in Windows 10.

You can set windows to be excluded under blacklist.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Alt & RButton:: 
   MouseGetPos, , , id,
   WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%

   ; disable for windows taskbar 
   If class not in Shell_TrayWnd
        WinClose, ahk_id %id%
return
```

This works perfectly for me.

(Optional) To prevent this from working on some windows, simply add the class of that window into the filter above. First, find out the ahkclass of your app from "Window spy" function, from the context menu Autohotkey tray icon. Then simply add the class name at the back.

```
   ;If class not in Shell_TrayWnd, <insert yourapp classname>
```

Adapted from,
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/43348-close-window-under-mouse/

Answer (score 1):

Modified tinker's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1554366/391770) for AHK v2

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

Alt & RButton:: {

MouseGetPos ,, &id
; detect the unique ID number of the window under the mouse cursor
; The window does not have to be active to be detected. Hidden windows cannot be detected
; WinID := WinExist("A")  ; alternative - but 'Active' window might not always be the intended target

winClass := WinGetClass("ahk_id " id) ; Retrieves the specified window's class name
If (winClass != "Shell_TrayWnd"                         ; exclude windows taskbar
 || winClass != "TopLevelWindowForOverflowXamlIsland"   ; System tray overflow window
 || winClass != "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow"            ; Notification Center
;|| winClass != "insert yourapp's classname"            ; uncomment to add more apps
    )
    WinClose("ahk_id " id)  ; sends a WM_CLOSE message to the target window
    ; PostMessage 0x0112, 0xF060,,, "ahk_id " id ; alternative - same as pressing Alt+F4 or clicking a window's close button in its title bar
}

^!F4::WinKill "A"

/* ; alternative
^!F4:: {
MouseGetPos ,, &id
ProcessClose WinGetProcessName("ahk_id " id)
}
; other methods to quit app - https://www.xda-developers.com/how-force-quit-applications-windows/
*/
```